# How do I make a priority queue that also takes into account the content of the element?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I feel I am over complicating things since I find there are so many boundary cases. This is an assignment for university so please ONLY GIVE ME HINTS and not code that I can copy/paste.
I am trying to make a priority queue that orders elements that contain a character. They should be arranged basted on priority value and then alphabetically if there is a conflict in priority. The problem I am having is inserting elements. Here is the code I currently have:

```
public void insertItem(int priority, char content) {
        boolean isSpecialCase = false;
        PList current;

        if (isEmpty()) {
            high = new PList(priority, content, null, null);
            low=high;
            System.out.println(content + " has been added to an empty list");
            isSpecialCase = true;

        }

        if (priority >= high.getPriority() && content >= high.getContent() && !isSpecialCase) {
            PList newItem = new PList(priority, content, high, null);
            high.setBehind(newItem);
            high = newItem;
            isSpecialCase = true;
            System.out.println(content + " has been added to a non empty list - highest priority");
        }
       if (priority < low.getPriority() && !isSpecialCase) {
            PList newItem = new PList(priority, content, null, low);
            low.setNext(newItem);
            low = newItem;
            isSpecialCase = true;
            System.out.println(content + " has been added to a non empty list - absolute lowest priority");
        }
        if (priority == low.getPriority() && content > low.getContent() && !isSpecialCase) {
            PList newItem = new PList(priority, content, low, low.getBehind());
            low.getBehind().setNext(newItem);
            low.setBehind(newItem);

            isSpecialCase = true;
            System.out.println(content + " has been added to a non empty list - lowest priority-highest char");

        }
        if (priority == low.getPriority() && !isSpecialCase) {
            if (content < low.getContent()) {
                PList newItem = new PList(priority, content, null, low);
                low.setNext(newItem);
                low = newItem;
                isSpecialCase = true;
                System.out.println(content + " has been added to a non empty list -lowest priority");
            }
        }



        current = high;
        while (current.getNext() != null && !isSpecialCase) {
            if (current.getPriority() >= priority) {
                if (current.getContent() > content) {
                    PList newItem = new PList(priority, content, current.getNext(), current);
                    current.getNext().setBehind(newItem);
                    current.setNext(newItem);
                    break;
                }
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }
```

It seems messy and somewhat repetitive so that is why I think I am on the wrong track. 
It works for most cases but for example I get a nullPointer when I run:

```
  PriQueue p = new PriQueue();
    p.insertItem(5, 'a');
    p.insertItem(5, 'a');
    p.insertItem(4, 'x');
    p.insertItem(4, 'a');
    p.insertItem(4, 'x');
```

And there are other cases where it just does not put all the elements in the queue without giving any error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Adding the stacktrace would be useful.

Comment: Are you familiar with a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)?

Comment: By heap, would I implement it by having the priority as a parent and the children would be arranged by character?

Answer (score 0):

I agree you are over complicating things, without giving an full on explanation you should consider implementing the `Comparable` interface on your `PList` items. Then when you insert a new item you can loop through your list until `listNode.compareTo(newNode) > 0` and that is where you insert it.